# Workflows for anonymous users

Tags: workflow, anonymous-authentication

I am trying to run a workflow on a list where anonymous read/write access is enabled (SP 2010).

The workflow works fine for authenticated users, but fails miserably for anonymous users ("failed to start" message).

I have tried both standard steps and impersonated steps, same result.

I am looking for clues, to see if the issue is specific to my environment, or a general issue with SharePoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christophe,

I think I answered by email as well, but in any case, here's a brief blog post that explains how and why:

http://blog.furuknap.net/enabling-declarative-workflows-for-anonymous-users-in-sp20102007

.b